# XSLT transform not providing correct output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having a slight problem with my XSLT transform.

I have the following XSLT;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><!-- removes the unrelated elements -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <!-- removes specified nodes from all elements -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>
   <!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="order">
      <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{replace}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </order>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | master_version"/>
   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="order">
      <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../master_version"/>
      </order>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Replace | master_version"/>
   <!-- renames element to specified name -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info1">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my original XML before transforming;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-01-07T16:58:58">

<order>
    <ORDERPK>3</ORDERPK>
    <job_id>S026500-1</job_id>
    <site_code>DG</site_code>
    <Replace>true</Replace>
    <job_description>TESTING</job_description>
    <order_qty>20000</order_qty>
    <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
    <depth>10</depth>
    <width>8</width>
    <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
    <text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
    <delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
    <delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
    <job_site>DG</job_site>
    <managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
    <is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
</order>
<master_version>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <version_id></version_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>true</version_common>
    <version_finished>false</version_finished>
    <version_description>Common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>TRUE</version_common>
    <version_finished>FALSE</version_finished>
    <version_description>Common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>1900</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>true</version_common>
    <version_finished>false</version_finished>
    <version_description>common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4ppCover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10.875 x 8.375</trim_size>
    <folio></folio>
    <data_format></data_format>
    <data_medium></data_medium>
    <data_due></data_due>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>240ppText</description>
    <pagination>240</pagination>
    <trim_size>103875 x 8.25</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4pp Cover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>12pp Text</description>
    <pagination>12</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>0</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4pp Cover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>24pp Text</description>
    <pagination>24</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<version>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<version>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<version>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>1</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4pp NEWS-NEWS COMM</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>9636</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>18000</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>1</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>2</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4pp Cover</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>63</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>30</task_run_speed>
    <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>2</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>120</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>240</task_run_speed>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4ppCover</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>1</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>24ppText</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_post_press>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <POST_x0020_PRESS>1</POST_x0020_PRESS>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_post_press>
<task_info_post_press>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <POST_x0020_PRESS>2</POST_x0020_PRESS>
    <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>120</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>240</task_run_speed>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_post_press>
<task_info_post_press>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <POST_x0020_PRESS>3</POST_x0020_PRESS>
    <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
</task_info_post_press>
<post_press_version>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
<post_press_version>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
<post_press_version>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
</dataroot>
```

My XML should look like this (I have cut down some of the information to make viewing the important part easier);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
          generated="2015-01-07T14:06:55">
   <order job_id="" site_code="" replace="true">
      <job_description>TESTDATA</job_description>
      <order_qty>1900</order_qty>
      <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
      <depth>10</depth>
      <width>8</width>
      <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
      <text_pagination>12</text_pagination>
      <delivery_commence_date>15/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
      <delivery_complete_date>15/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
      <job_site>DG</job_site>
      <managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
      <is_managing_printer>TRUE</is_managing_printer>
      <cust_order_ref>776031</cust_order_ref>
      <cust_code>Test</cust_code>
      <site_cce_name>Jamie</site_cce_name>
      <site_cce_email>JamesBrace@dstoutput.co.uk</site_cce_email>
      <sales_person_name>Jamie Brace</sales_person_name>
      <sales_person_email>JamesBrace@dstouput.co.uk</sales_person_email>
      <master_version>
         <version_id/>
         <version_code>COMM</version_code>
         <version_common>true</version_common>
         <version_finished>false</version_finished>
         <version_description>Common</version_description>
         <version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
         <version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
      </master_version>
   </order>
</dataroot>
```

But it looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
          generated="2015-01-07T14:06:55">
   <order job_id="" site_code="" replace="true">
      <job_description>TESTDATA</job_description>
      <order_qty>1900</order_qty>
      <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
      <depth>10</depth>
      <width>8</width>
      <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
      <text_pagination>12</text_pagination>
      <delivery_commence_date>15/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
      <delivery_complete_date>15/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
      <job_site>DG</job_site>
      <managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
      <is_managing_printer>TRUE</is_managing_printer>
      <cust_order_ref>776031</cust_order_ref>
      <cust_code>Test</cust_code>
      <site_cce_name>Jamie</site_cce_name>
      <site_cce_email>JamesBrace@dstoutput.co.uk</site_cce_email>
      <sales_person_name>Jamie Brace</sales_person_name>
      <sales_person_email>JamesBrace@dstouput.co.uk</sales_person_email>
      <master_version>
         <ORDER>1</ORDER>
         <version_id/>
         <version_code>COMM</version_code>
         <version_common>true</version_common>
         <version_finished>false</version_finished>
         <version_description>Common</version_description>
         <version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
         <version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
      </master_version>
      <master_version>
         <ORDER>2</ORDER>
         <version_code>COMM</version_code>
         <version_common>TRUE</version_common>
         <version_finished>FALSE</version_finished>
         <version_description>Common</version_description>
         <version_nett_qty>1900</version_nett_qty>
         <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
      </master_version>
   </order>
</dataroot>
```

The "master_version" element should be nested after the transform, which it is, but the transform is also telling it to delete all the element if the "ORDER" node in "master_version" is not equal to "ORDERPK" in "order", which it doesn't appear to be doing.

Any ideas?

Also I have been told that my XSLT isn't formatted very well, could anybody possibly help with that?

Comment: I've reformatted your XSLT code. For your future questions, beautify the result yourself, for example with http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer. Also, please edit your post and include the XML input document. And, very importantly: Do not simply throw two XML outputs at us, _explain_ how they are different.

Comment: Your XML outputs were both malformed - please check for well-formedness before submitting a question. Also, your question title is a very unhelpful one. Think of something more informative than "transform not working".

Comment: SO isn't a free debugging service. Questions like this are not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that link is definitely useful!

Comment: Zoff, I'm aware of this but I'm very inexperienced with XML and XSLT, and googling what I'm trying to create doesn't really pay off since I don't understand it hugely. I'd rather ask a question here and get an answer that actually means something to me instead of spending days searching for something that might or might not be relevant to me.

Comment: Questions asking to help debug are ok as long as they follow this rule (taken from the "close" options): Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've tried to give as much information as possible here.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense. Maybe I'm missing something but your output doesn't match your input at all. For example `job_description`, `order_qty`, etc. is different. That makes an answer harder because we are left to guess whether that's just a copy/paste issue (probably) or if the XSLT is supposed to change those values.

Comment: Also, you said "I have cut down some of the information to make viewing the important part easier". If the information is in the input and not in your output, we are going to assume that it is supposed to be stripped by the XSLT. By looking at your original XSLT (with 5 identity transforms), I would recommend not cutting down your output to try to make it easier on us. It will just make the answer that much more confusing for you.

Comment: Also explain from which portion of your input xml the data for nodes after "is_managing_printer" is coming, as mentioned in your output xml

Comment: @Saurav - It's probably an issue of the input not matching the output at all. In addition to "is_managing_printer", all of the site and salesperson data that is in the output isn't in the input. There's probably a lot more than that too, but I'm done looking for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your XSLT. Focusing on the problem in hand, one issue is in one of your "order" templates uses an `xsl:copy-of`

```
 <xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../master_version"/>
     </order>
 </xsl:template>
```

Before going further though, you have two templates matching "order". This is strictly speaking specified as an error in XSLT. You may not actually be seeing an error because some processors ignore the duplicate templates, and only use the last one. You should delete the first one.

Anyway, by using `xsl:copy-of` it is simply going to copy all `master_version` elements here, regardless of any other template matches here. You need to use `xsl:apply-templates`

```
<xsl:template match="order">
   <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
   </order>
</xsl:template>
```

But this on its own will not work because of these two template matches (although it is an error to have to templates both matching just `master_version` as mentioned)

```
<xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | master_version"/>

<xsl:template match="Replace | master_version"/>
```

Remove the `master_version` from these template matches, and leave just this existing one

```
<xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
```

(Note that when an element is matched with a condition, it will actually have a higher priority than one that just matched `master_version`, so this is not an error in this instance).

You would also be there at this point, but you would find now that `master_version` would still be output in their current place too. To get around this, you can have a template matching `dataroot` and add code to explicitly ignore the `master_version` elements at that point

```
<xsl:template match="dataroot">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::master_version)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT. It may not give the precise output you specified, but it should solve the problem on your `master_version` elements which you asked about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>

   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <!-- removes specified nodes from all elements -->

   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>

   <!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="dataroot">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::master_version)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | Replace"/>

   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="order">
      <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
      </order>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info1">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the multiple identity templates have been removed, as mentioned by Daniel Haley in comments.

Comment: You deserve a -100 for encouraging such poor questions but a +101 for your effort and compassion.

Comment: I second that, you've just earned _Nicest XSLT Person 2015_ - again.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much there, thank you very much! I've still got an issue with attributes not being applied to "order" but I appreciate this, thank you! I'm sorry if my questions aren't up to scratch, I'm new to XSLT and I would like to be given a chance..

Comment: In the template matching "order" try replacing `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` as that then applies the current attributes too. And don't give up!