# Why are my XML elements losing their data when being transformed to attributes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm outputting data from an Access Database to XML, ready for import into a foreign system we use in my company. The import has to be formatted in a specific way, and I'm trying to use an XSLT transform to format it like this.

This is the sample import from the foreign system;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tg:orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
    <!-- the following xml describes a 244pp perfect bound magazine with an order quantity of 176277 copies -->
    <!-- There are 8 versions and all forms are versioned -->
    <!-- version ONT NEWS (176,277 copies)  -->
    <!-- version BAL OF CAN NEWS  (19,402 copies)  -->
    <!-- version BAL OF CAN NEWS  (9,411 copies)  -->
    <!-- version BC NEWS  (5,012 copies)  -->
    <!-- version QUE NEWS  (3,777 copies)  -->
    <!-- version ONT SUBS  (88,874 copies)  -->
    <!-- version BAL OF CAN SUBS  (19,407 copies)  -->
    <!-- version BC SUBS  (18,760 copies)  -->
    <!-- version QUE SUBS  (11,619 copies)  -->
    <!-- NOTE: All quantities should be the number of good copies required from the relevant task -->
    <!-- For example, for a press run, of 215,000 that requires 10,000 extra for bindery overs should have a quantity of  225,000 -->

    <!-- job id must be a unique 10 character alphanumeric reference and is used to match details in a foreign system -->
    <!-- site code must be a unique 2 character alphanumeric reference that is used to determine the site where the order will be produced. This must match a site code in Technique -->
    <tg:order tg:job_id="SC10268" tg:site_code="SC" tg:replace="true">
        <tg:job_description>STJ Import - AUG 2007</tg:job_description>
        <tg:order_qty>176277</tg:order_qty>
        <!-- finishing style should be WS for saddle stitched or PB for perfect bound -->
        <tg:finishing_style>PB</tg:finishing_style>
        <!-- overall finished trim size and extent -->
        <tg:depth>8.25</tg:depth>
        <tg:width>10.875</tg:width>
        <tg:cover_pagination>4</tg:cover_pagination>
        <tg:text_pagination>240</tg:text_pagination>
        <!-- deadline dates for the job are specified here -->
        <tg:delivery_commence_date>2007-11-04</tg:delivery_commence_date>
        <tg:delivery_complete_date>2007-11-05</tg:delivery_complete_date>
        <!-- job site and managing printer should default to your site code we set up for the trial -->
        <tg:job_site>SC</tg:job_site>
        <tg:managing_printer>SC</tg:managing_printer>
        <!-- job site and managing printer should default to true for the trial -->
        <tg:is_managing_printer>true</tg:is_managing_printer>
        <!-- customer purchase order reference if known -->
        <tg:cust_order_ref>776030</tg:cust_order_ref>
        <!-- customer code should be a unique reference that we will use to add customer detail and avoid duplicates -->
        <!-- see seperate company import specification for further company details -->
        <!-- Customer code MUST match an CompanyShortCode in the Company DB -->
        <tg:cust_code>Sears</tg:cust_code>
        <!-- add as many job related contacts as you need -->
        <tg:cust_contact tg:cust_contact_code="jill.summers@sears.com"/>
        <tg:cust_contact tg:cust_contact_code="simon.caldwell@sears.com"/>
        <!-- account exec / CSR details - the email address will be used as a unique key to avoid duplicates -->
        <!-- we will add new CSR's (based on email address to the list of available CSR's -->
        <tg:site_cce_name>Cathy Noble</tg:site_cce_name>
        <tg:site_cce_phone>(847) 466 1008</tg:site_cce_phone>
        <tg:site_cce_mobile>(847) 477 2008</tg:site_cce_mobile>
        <tg:site_cce_email>cathy.noble@superior.com</tg:site_cce_email>
        <!-- sales rep details - the email address will be used as a unique key to avoid duplicates -->
        <!-- we will add new sales reps (based on email address to the list of available sales reps -->
        <tg:sales_person_name>Sam Brown</tg:sales_person_name>
        <tg:sales_person_phone>(847) 466 1001</tg:sales_person_phone>
        <tg:sales_person_mobile>(847) 477 2001</tg:sales_person_mobile>
        <tg:sales_person_email>sam.brown@superior.com</tg:sales_person_email>
        <!-- master press / printed version details - there MUST always be a COMM version regardless of whether it is used -->
        <!-- If no common version is printed, add the COMM version with a qty equal to sum of all version splits and set version_finished to "false" -->
        <!-- version_id is an internal Technique reference and can be left empty for the import -->
        <!-- WIT XML: press_version -->
        <!-- These are the print versions. version_finished is false as they are WIP components  -->
        <!-- DUMMY Common version as there is no common component -->
        <tg:master_version>
            <tg:version_id/>
            <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
            <tg:version_common>true</tg:version_common>
            <tg:version_finished>false</tg:version_finished>
            <tg:version_description>Common</tg:version_description>
            <tg:version_nett_qty>176262</tg:version_nett_qty>
            <tg:version_special_qty>10</tg:version_special_qty>
        </tg:master_version>
        <tg:press_section>
            <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
            <tg:sequence_id>1</tg:sequence_id>
            <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
            <tg:description>4ppCover</tg:description>
            <tg:pagination>4</tg:pagination>
            <tg:trim_size>10.875 x 8.375</tg:trim_size>
            <tg:folio/>
            <tg:data_format/>
            <tg:data_medium/>
            <tg:data_due/>
            <tg:version>
                <!-- task_sub_job_id's MUST be Unique system wide as will be used as part references -->
                <!-- Resources, MR times, run times and press speeds need to be entered here -->
                <!-- These are planned values, but may change when the job is actually scheduled -->
                <!-- The values entered here will be preserved, regardless of how the job is scheduled -->
                <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
                <tg:task_info tg:confirmed="true" tg:maintenance="false" tg:provisional="false">
                    <tg:task_sub_job_id>SC10268-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                    <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                    <tg:task_description>4pp NEWS-NEWS COMM</tg:task_description>
                    <tg:task_qty_rqd>9636</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                    <tg:task_resource_id>116</tg:task_resource_id>
                    <tg:task_mr_mins>120</tg:task_mr_mins>
                    <tg:task_run_mins>240</tg:task_run_mins>
                    <tg:task_run_speed>18000</tg:task_run_speed>
                    <tg:task_notes>Task Notes</tg:task_notes>
                    <tg:task_no_up>4</tg:task_no_up>
                    <tg:task_deadline_date_time/>
                    <tg:task_pdt>0.0</tg:task_pdt>
                </tg:task_info>
            </tg:version>
        </tg:press_section>
        <tg:post_press_version>
            <tg:post_press_version_op_id>0</tg:post_press_version_op_id>
            <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
            <tg:post_press_resource_type>PB</tg:post_press_resource_type>
            <tg:task_info tg:confirmed="true" tg:maintenance="false" tg:provisional="false">
                <tg:task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                <tg:task_description>Perfect Binding</tg:task_description>
                <tg:task_qty_rqd>19402</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                <tg:task_resource_id>130</tg:task_resource_id>
                <tg:task_mr_mins>120</tg:task_mr_mins>
                <tg:task_run_mins>240</tg:task_run_mins>
                <tg:task_run_speed>7500</tg:task_run_speed>
                <tg:task_notes>Task Notes</tg:task_notes>
                <tg:task_no_up>1</tg:task_no_up>
                <tg:task_deadline_date_time/>
                <tg:task_pdt>0.0</tg:task_pdt>
            </tg:task_info>
        </tg:post_press_version>
        <!-- Schedule information is required if  the jobs are to bypass the To Do List and go directly to the planning board -->
        <!-- Scheduel information (without start and end time/dates is also required to link tasks together in ToDo list (i.e. two streams). See example below -->
        <!-- A scheduled item can include multiple tasks (e.g. multiple deliveries/ganged jobs -->
        <!-- Each <schedule node> corresponds to the top half of the component details dialog in Technique Scheduling (when a task is double-clicked) -->
        <!-- Each <schedule_task> node refers to a task listed elsewhere in the XML -->
        <!-- This node corresponds to the bottom half of the component details dialog in Technique Scheduling (when a task is double-clicked) -->
        <!-- The task_sub_job_id is the unique identifier for a task. For press runs the sub-job no is typically derived from: <Job No>-<Sig><VersCode> -->
        <!-- For postpress operations the sub-job no is typically derived from: <Job No>-<WIP Part Ref> -->
        <!-- Schedule Info -->
        <tg:schedule>
            <tg:schedule_start_date_time>2007-11-05T06:20:00</tg:schedule_start_date_time>
            <tg:schedule_end_date_time>2007-11-05T12:15:00</tg:schedule_end_date_time>
            <tg:schedule_multi_task_desc />
            <tg:schedule_resource_id>116</tg:schedule_resource_id>
            <tg:schedule_mr_mins>120</tg:schedule_mr_mins>
            <tg:schedule_run_mins>450</tg:schedule_run_mins>
            <tg:schedule_run_speed>30000</tg:schedule_run_speed>
            <tg:schedule_no_of_staff>2</tg:schedule_no_of_staff>
            <tg:task_pdt>10.0</tg:task_pdt>
            <tg:schedule_crit_delay_mins>0</tg:schedule_crit_delay_mins>
            <tg:schedule_locked>false</tg:schedule_locked>
            <tg:schedule_task>
                <tg:task_sub_job_id>SC10268-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                <tg:schedule_task_stream>1</tg:schedule_task_stream>
                <tg:schedule_qty>10000</tg:schedule_qty>
            </tg:schedule_task>
        </tg:schedule>
        <!-- Perfect Binder -->
        <tg:schedule>
            <tg:schedule_start_date_time>2007-11-05T12:39:00</tg:schedule_start_date_time>
            <tg:schedule_end_date_time>2007-11-05T22:39:00</tg:schedule_end_date_time>
            <tg:schedule_multi_task_desc />
            <tg:schedule_resource_id>130</tg:schedule_resource_id>
            <tg:schedule_mr_mins>120</tg:schedule_mr_mins> 
            <tg:schedule_run_mins>480</tg:schedule_run_mins>
            <tg:schedule_run_speed>8000</tg:schedule_run_speed>
            <tg:schedule_no_of_staff>4</tg:schedule_no_of_staff>
            <tg:task_pdt>0.0</tg:task_pdt>
            <tg:schedule_crit_delay_mins>0</tg:schedule_crit_delay_mins>
            <tg:schedule_locked>false</tg:schedule_locked>
            <tg:schedule_task>
                <tg:task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                <tg:schedule_task_stream>1</tg:schedule_task_stream>
                <tg:schedule_qty>11619</tg:schedule_qty>
            </tg:schedule_task>
        </tg:schedule>

    </tg:order>
</tg:orders>
```

I'm only actually creating data for some of the sections, so some of it can be ignored. This is the XML that is outputted from Access before being transformed;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-01-08T09:33:08">
<order>
    <ORDERPK>1</ORDERPK>
    <job_id>SC10268</job_id>
    <site_code>SC</site_code>
    <Replace>true</Replace>
    <job_description>STJ Import - AUG 2007</job_description>
    <order_qty>176277</order_qty>
    <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
    <depth>8.25</depth>
    <width>10.875</width>
    <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
    <text_pagination>240</text_pagination>
    <delivery_commence_date>2007-11-04</delivery_commence_date>
    <delivery_complete_date>2007-11-05</delivery_complete_date>
    <job_site>SC</job_site>
    <managing_printer>SC</managing_printer>
    <is_managing_printer>true</is_managing_printer>
    <cust_order_ref>776030</cust_order_ref>
    <cust_code>Sears</cust_code>
    <cust_contact></cust_contact>
    <site_cce_name>Cathy Noble</site_cce_name>
    <site_cce_phone>(847) 466 1008</site_cce_phone>
    <site_cce_mobile>(847) 477 2008</site_cce_mobile>
    <site_cce_email>cathy.noble@superior.com</site_cce_email>
    <sales_person_name>Sam Brown</sales_person_name>
    <sales_person_phone>(847) 466 1001</sales_person_phone>
    <sales_person_mobile>(847) 477 2001</sales_person_mobile>
    <sales_person_email>sam.brown@superior.com</sales_person_email>
</order>
<master_version>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <version_id></version_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>true</version_common>
    <version_finished>false</version_finished>
    <version_description>Common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>TRUE</version_common>
    <version_finished>FALSE</version_finished>
    <version_description>Common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>1900</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <version_common>true</version_common>
    <version_finished>false</version_finished>
    <version_description>common</version_description>
    <version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
    <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4ppCover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10.875 x 8.375</trim_size>
    <folio></folio>
    <data_format></data_format>
    <data_medium></data_medium>
    <data_due></data_due>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>240ppText</description>
    <pagination>240</pagination>
    <trim_size>103875 x 8.25</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4pp Cover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>12pp Text</description>
    <pagination>12</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>0</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4pp Cover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>24pp Text</description>
    <pagination>24</pagination>
    <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<version>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<version>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<version>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>1</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4pp NEWS-NEWS COMM</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>9636</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>18000</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>1</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>2</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4pp Cover</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>63</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>30</task_run_speed>
    <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>2</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>120</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>240</task_run_speed>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4ppCover</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
    <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>1</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>24ppText</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_post_press>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <POST_x0020_PRESS>1</POST_x0020_PRESS>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_post_press>
<task_info_post_press>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <POST_x0020_PRESS>2</POST_x0020_PRESS>
    <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>120</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>240</task_run_speed>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info_post_press>
<task_info_post_press>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <POST_x0020_PRESS>3</POST_x0020_PRESS>
    <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
</task_info_post_press>
<post_press_version>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
<post_press_version>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
<post_press_version>
    <ORDER>3</ORDER>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
</dataroot>
```

This is my XSLT;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <!-- removes the unrelated elements -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>

   <!-- removes specified nodes from all elements -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>

   <!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="order">
      <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{replace}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </order>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace"/>
   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="order">
      <order job_id="{@job_id}" site_code="{@site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
      </order>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Replace"/>
   <!-- renames element to specified name -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info1">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="dataroot">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::master_version)]"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the output XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot generated="2015-01-08T09:37:15" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<order job_id="" site_code="" replace="true">
    <job_description>STJ Import - AUG 2007</job_description>
    <order_qty>176277</order_qty>
    <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
    <depth>8.25</depth>
    <width>10.875</width>
    <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
    <text_pagination>240</text_pagination>
    <delivery_commence_date>2007-11-04</delivery_commence_date>
    <delivery_complete_date>2007-11-05</delivery_complete_date>
    <job_site>SC</job_site>
    <managing_printer>SC</managing_printer>
    <is_managing_printer>true</is_managing_printer>
    <cust_order_ref>776030</cust_order_ref>
    <cust_code>Sears</cust_code>
    <cust_contact></cust_contact>
    <site_cce_name>Cathy Noble</site_cce_name>
    <site_cce_phone>(847) 466 1008</site_cce_phone>
    <site_cce_mobile>(847) 477 2008</site_cce_mobile>
    <site_cce_email>cathy.noble@superior.com</site_cce_email>
    <sales_person_name>Sam Brown</sales_person_name>
    <sales_person_phone>(847) 466 1001</sales_person_phone>
    <sales_person_mobile>(847) 477 2001</sales_person_mobile>
    <sales_person_email>sam.brown@superior.com</sales_person_email>
    <master_version>
        <version_id></version_id>
        <version_code>COMM</version_code>
        <version_common>true</version_common>
        <version_finished>false</version_finished>
        <version_description>Common</version_description>
        <version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
        <version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
    </master_version>
</order>
<press_section>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>4ppCover</description>
    <pagination>4</pagination>
    <trim_size>10.875 x 8.375</trim_size>
    <folio></folio>
    <data_format></data_format>
    <data_medium></data_medium>
    <data_due></data_due>
</press_section>
<press_section>
    <signature_id>001</signature_id>
    <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
    <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
    <description>240ppText</description>
    <pagination>240</pagination>
    <trim_size>103875 x 8.25</trim_size>
</press_section>
<version>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<task_info1>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>4pp NEWS-NEWS COMM</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>9636</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>18000</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info1>
<task_info1>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info1>
<task_info2>
    <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
    <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
    <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
    <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
    <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
    <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
    <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
    <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
    <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
    <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
    <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
    <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
</task_info2>
<post_press_version>
    <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
    <version_code>COMM</version_code>
    <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
</post_press_version>
</dataroot>
```

It is changing the element to an attribute, but it's not bringing any data with it, leaving the attribute blank.

Ideally, the "order" element should look like this;

```
<order job_id="SC10268" site_code="SC" replace="true">
```

Eventually, I want to also nest the other elements inside Order, and then inside other elements within Order, but for now I managed to get "master_version" nested thanks to other users on this site helping me out massively!

If anyone knows how to get the element to become an attribute, and not lose it's data, then I'd appreciate the help. If any more information is needed, please let me know. Thanks!

Also as a side note, is the "tg:" before each node a part of XML, or do you think that is just part of the foreign system's import?

Comment: may I ask why someone has downvoted this? I'm not sure what else I can add to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your XSLT code is a mess really and you did not exactly read what [Tim wrote with endless goodwill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826274/1987598). For example, **there are still several identity templates. What for?**

---

`job_id` and `site_code` are not attributes. They are element nodes. Therefore, change the template that matches `order` to

```
<xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
    </order>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, the output includes

```
<order job_id="SC10268" site_code="SC" replace="true">
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! looking at it, I probably should've seen that but I guess I didn't look hard enough!