# How do I nest more than one element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

EDIT; totally redone the question.

Thanks for all your help so far Tim, really do appreciate it!

I've copied that XSLT you posted, and it works perfectly fine, thank you for that! This is what I'm currently struggling with;

The XSLT currently only nest's "master_version" in the "order" element. I'm now trying to nest other elements in "order", however it's this that is causing the problems.

Here is my current XML input;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-01-12T10:09:45">
 <order>
  <ORDERPK>3</ORDERPK>
  <job_id>S026500-1</job_id>
  <site_code>DG</site_code>
  <Replace>true</Replace>
  <job_description>TESTING</job_description>
  <order_qty>20000</order_qty>
  <finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
  <depth>10</depth>
  <width>8</width>
  <cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
  <text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
  <delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
  <delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
  <job_site>DG</job_site>
  <managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
  <is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
 </order>
 <master_version>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <version_id></version_id>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
  <version_common>true</version_common>
  <version_finished>false</version_finished>
  <version_description>Common</version_description>
  <version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
  <version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
 </master_version>
 <master_version>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
  <version_common>TRUE</version_common>
  <version_finished>FALSE</version_finished>
  <version_description>Common</version_description>
  <version_nett_qty>1900</version_nett_qty>
  <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
 </master_version>
 <master_version>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
  <version_common>true</version_common>
  <version_finished>false</version_finished>
  <version_description>common</version_description>
  <version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
  <version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
 </master_version>
 <press_section>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <signature_id>001</signature_id>
  <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
  <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
  <description>4ppCover</description>
  <pagination>4</pagination>
  <trim_size>10.875 x 8.375</trim_size>
  <folio></folio>
  <data_format></data_format>
  <data_medium></data_medium>
  <data_due></data_due>
 </press_section>
 <press_section>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <signature_id>001</signature_id>
  <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
  <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
  <description>240ppText</description>
  <pagination>240</pagination>
  <trim_size>103875 x 8.25</trim_size>
 </press_section>
 <press_section>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <signature_id>001</signature_id>
  <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
  <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
  <description>4pp Cover</description>
  <pagination>4</pagination>
  <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
 </press_section>
 <press_section>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <signature_id>001</signature_id>
  <sequence_id>0</sequence_id>
  <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
  <description>4pp Cover</description>
  <pagination>4</pagination>
  <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
 </press_section>
 <press_section>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <signature_id>001</signature_id>
  <sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
  <sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
  <description>24pp Text</description>
  <pagination>24</pagination>
  <trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
 </press_section>
 <version>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
 </version>
 <version>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
 </version>
 <version>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
 </version>
 <task_info_press_section>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>1</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
  <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>4pp NEWS-NEWS COMM</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>9636</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
  <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
  <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
  <task_run_speed>18000</task_run_speed>
  <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
  <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
  <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
  <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
 </task_info_press_section>
 <task_info_press_section>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>1</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
  <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
  <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
  <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
  <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
  <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
  <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
  <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
  <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
 </task_info_press_section>
 <task_info_press_section>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>2</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
  <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>4pp Cover</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
  <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
  <task_run_mins>63</task_run_mins>
  <task_run_speed>30</task_run_speed>
  <task_no_up>4</task_no_up>
  <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
 </task_info_press_section>
 <task_info_press_section>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>2</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
  <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
  <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
  <task_run_mins>120</task_run_mins>
  <task_run_speed>240</task_run_speed>
  <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
  <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
 </task_info_press_section>
 <task_info_press_section>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
  <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>4ppCover</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
 </task_info_press_section>
 <task_info_press_section>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
  <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>1</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>24ppText</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
 </task_info_press_section>
 <task_info_post_press>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <POST_x0020_PRESS>1</POST_x0020_PRESS>
  <task_sub_job_id>SC10268-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>19402</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
  <task_mr_mins>120</task_mr_mins>
  <task_run_mins>240</task_run_mins>
  <task_run_speed>7500</task_run_speed>
  <task_notes>Task Notes</task_notes>
  <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
  <task_deadline_date_time></task_deadline_date_time>
  <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
 </task_info_post_press>
 <task_info_post_press>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <POST_x0020_PRESS>2</POST_x0020_PRESS>
  <task_sub_job_id>S019191-9-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>1900</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
  <task_mr_mins>20</task_mr_mins>
  <task_run_mins>120</task_run_mins>
  <task_run_speed>240</task_run_speed>
  <task_no_up>1</task_no_up>
  <task_pdt>0.0</task_pdt>
 </task_info_post_press>
 <task_info_post_press>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <POST_x0020_PRESS>3</POST_x0020_PRESS>
  <task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</task_sub_job_id>
  <task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
  <task_description>Perfect Binding</task_description>
  <task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
  <task_resource_id>10</task_resource_id>
 </task_info_post_press>
 <post_press_version>
  <ORDER>1</ORDER>
  <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
  <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
 </post_press_version>
 <post_press_version>
  <ORDER>2</ORDER>
  <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
  <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
 </post_press_version>
 <post_press_version>
  <ORDER>3</ORDER>
  <post_press_version_op_id>0</post_press_version_op_id>
  <version_code>COMM</version_code>
  <post_press_resource_type>PB</post_press_resource_type>
 </post_press_version>
</dataroot>
```

This is my output XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tg:orders xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
   <tg:order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="true">
      <tg:job_description>TESTING</tg:job_description>
      <tg:order_qty>20000</tg:order_qty>
      <tg:finishing_style>PB</tg:finishing_style>
      <tg:depth>10</tg:depth>
      <tg:width>8</tg:width>
      <tg:cover_pagination>4</tg:cover_pagination>
      <tg:text_pagination>24</tg:text_pagination>
      <tg:delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</tg:delivery_commence_date>
      <tg:delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</tg:delivery_complete_date>
      <tg:job_site>DG</tg:job_site>
      <tg:managing_printer>DG</tg:managing_printer>
      <tg:is_managing_printer>True</tg:is_managing_printer>
      <tg:master_version>
         <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
         <tg:version_common>true</tg:version_common>
         <tg:version_finished>false</tg:version_finished>
         <tg:version_description>common</tg:version_description>
         <tg:version_nett_qty>20000</tg:version_nett_qty>
         <tg:version_special_qty>0</tg:version_special_qty>
      </tg:master_version>
   </tg:order>
   <tg:press_section>
      <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
      <tg:sequence_id>0</tg:sequence_id>
      <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
      <tg:description>4pp Cover</tg:description>
      <tg:pagination>4</tg:pagination>
      <tg:trim_size>10 x 8</tg:trim_size>
   </tg:press_section>
   <tg:press_section>
      <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
      <tg:sequence_id>1</tg:sequence_id>
      <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
      <tg:description>24pp Text</tg:description>
      <tg:pagination>24</tg:pagination>
      <tg:trim_size>10 x 8</tg:trim_size>
   </tg:press_section>
   <tg:version>
      <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
   </tg:version>
   <tg:task_info1>
      <tg:task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
      <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
      <tg:task_description>4ppCover</tg:task_description>
      <tg:task_qty_rqd>20000</tg:task_qty_rqd>
      <tg:task_resource_id>2</tg:task_resource_id>
   </tg:task_info1>
   <tg:task_info1>
      <tg:task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
      <tg:task_seq_id>1</tg:task_seq_id>
      <tg:task_description>24ppText</tg:task_description>
      <tg:task_qty_rqd>20000</tg:task_qty_rqd>
      <tg:task_resource_id>2</tg:task_resource_id>
   </tg:task_info1>
   <tg:task_info2>
      <tg:task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
      <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
      <tg:task_description>Perfect Binding</tg:task_description>
      <tg:task_qty_rqd>20000</tg:task_qty_rqd>
      <tg:task_resource_id>10</tg:task_resource_id>
   </tg:task_info2>
   <tg:post_press_version>
      <tg:post_press_version_op_id>0</tg:post_press_version_op_id>
      <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
      <tg:post_press_resource_type>PB</tg:post_press_resource_type>
   </tg:post_press_version>
</tg:orders>
```

This is my desired output;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tg:orders xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
   <tg:order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="true">
      <tg:job_description>TESTING</tg:job_description>
      <tg:order_qty>20000</tg:order_qty>
      <tg:finishing_style>PB</tg:finishing_style>
      <tg:depth>10</tg:depth>
      <tg:width>8</tg:width>
      <tg:cover_pagination>4</tg:cover_pagination>
      <tg:text_pagination>24</tg:text_pagination>
      <tg:delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</tg:delivery_commence_date>
      <tg:delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</tg:delivery_complete_date>
      <tg:job_site>DG</tg:job_site>
      <tg:managing_printer>DG</tg:managing_printer>
      <tg:is_managing_printer>True</tg:is_managing_printer>
      <tg:master_version>
         <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
         <tg:version_common>true</tg:version_common>
         <tg:version_finished>false</tg:version_finished>
         <tg:version_description>common</tg:version_description>
         <tg:version_nett_qty>20000</tg:version_nett_qty>
         <tg:version_special_qty>0</tg:version_special_qty>
      </tg:master_version>
      <tg:press_section>
         <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
         <tg:sequence_id>0</tg:sequence_id>
         <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
         <tg:description>4pp Cover</tg:description>
         <tg:pagination>4</tg:pagination>
         <tg:trim_size>10 x 8</tg:trim_size>
         <tg:version>
            <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
            <tg:task_info1>
               <tg:task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
               <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
               <tg:task_description>4ppCover</tg:task_description>
               <tg:task_qty_rqd>20000</tg:task_qty_rqd>
               <tg:task_resource_id>2</tg:task_resource_id>
            </tg:task_info1>
         </tg:version>
      </tg:press_section>
      <tg:press_section>
         <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
         <tg:sequence_id>1</tg:sequence_id>
         <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
         <tg:description>24pp Text</tg:description>
         <tg:pagination>24</tg:pagination>
         <tg:trim_size>10 x 8</tg:trim_size>
         <tg:version>
            <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
            <tg:task_info>
               <tg:task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
               <tg:task_seq_id>1</tg:task_seq_id>
               <tg:task_description>24ppText</tg:task_description>
               <tg:task_qty_rqd>20000</tg:task_qty_rqd>
               <tg:task_resource_id>2</tg:task_resource_id>
            </tg:task_info>
         </tg:version>
      </tg:press_section>
      <tg:post_press_version>
         <tg:post_press_version_op_id>0</tg:post_press_version_op_id>
         <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
         <tg:post_press_resource_type>PB</tg:post_press_resource_type>
         <tg:task_info2>
            <tg:task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-1COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
            <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
            <tg:task_description>Perfect Binding</tg:task_description>
            <tg:task_qty_rqd>20000</tg:task_qty_rqd>
            <tg:task_resource_id>10</tg:task_resource_id>
         </tg:task_info2>
      </tg:post_press_version>
   </tg:order>
</tg:orders>
```

I have 2 XSLT's, one is to format the XML how I need, and the other is a Namespace declaration to apply to the whole XML file once the formatting is done;

Here is XSLT1;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <!-- creates new root element -->

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </orders>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Commented out as this template occurs later -->
   <!--
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    -->

   <!-- matches the template saying remove elements if not matching the order element -->

   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>


   <!-- removes specified nodes from all elements -->

   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>


   <!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- CHANGED "order" to "dataroot" -->
   <xsl:template match="dataroot">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::master_version)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | Replace"/>


   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

   <!-- nests elements within order -->

       <xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
    </order>
   </xsl:template>



   <!-- renames elements to desired name -->

   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info1">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is XSLT2;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com"
    version="1.2">

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="tg:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.technique-group.com">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dataroot">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Essentially, I want to nest my elements to the following structure;

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <info>1</info>
        <master_version>
        <info>1</info>
        </master_version>
        <press_section>
        <info>1</info>
            <version>
            <info>1</info>
               <task_info_press_section>
               <info>1</info>
               </task_info_press_section>
            </version>
        </press_section>
        <post_press_version
        <info>1</info>
            <task_info_post_press>
            <info>1</info>
            </task_info_post_press>
        </post_press_version>
    </order>
</orders>
```

Comment: The answer I gave to a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823597/xslt-transform-not-providing-correct-output) should solve this. The problem in your new XSLT is that you still have two templates matching "order" which is an error. The first template should be changed to match "dataroot" instead of "order" as that template then contains the code to ignore the `master_version` elements under it. All should then be good!

Comment: Also, you have two "identity" templates in your XSLT (The templates that matches `@*|node()`). You should remove one of them. Thanks!

Comment: @Jamie: When you get an answer on StackOverflow, please take the time to understand it. Copying & pasting an answer you don't understand and then simply coming back with code that isn't your own as soon as something doesn't work isn't a very nice thing to do.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you! Yeah I see the problem now, I've changed it to "dataroot" and also removed the second identity template.

Comment: @Tomalak, I do try to understand it but I find XML a very confusing and intimidating language to try and learn, I'm only really used to VBA and I'm no expert there either!

Comment: @TimC I have to say I'm more than a little confused now, if I change the first template to "dataroot" instead of "order", it does remove the "master_version" element, but then it also makes a copy of "order" underneath the first "order" element, as well as having "master_version" un-nested underneath it! I'll edit the question to show this.

Comment: Take a look at http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQf where I have given an example. All I have done to the XSLT is copy the XSLT from this question, removed one of the identity templates, and changed the first "order" matching template to match "dataroot" instead. I do note your new output samples contain the "tg:" prefix, so it might be worth showing the latest your XSLT if it differs a bit. If you do edit the question, it might help to simplify it a bit. Show a complete XML input sample, the sole latest XSLT you are using, and the output you expect. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC thank you very much for that, it's definitely a help! I've totally edited the question as much as I can to show where I'm currently at!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to nest all other elements under `order` the first thing to do is to change the existing `xsl:apply-templates` in the `dataroot` matching template from this....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::master_version)]"/>
```

To this....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*)]|order"/>
```

This copies all attributes, plus all nodes that are not elements, and the `order` element.

(Note, you could simplify it to `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(self::order)]"/>` but this would not pick up text nodes, comments or processing instructions, which are all "nodes")

Then, in the template that matches `order` change the existing `xsl:apply-templates` from this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
```

To this, so it will select all elements that are not `order` elements`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::order)]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </orders>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>


   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="dataroot">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*)]|order"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | Replace"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::order)]"/>
    </order>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info1">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that in your second XSLT, I notice you are removing the `dataroot` element. It might be worth doing that action in the first XSLT instead, as that makes your second XSLT more generic then. Just change the existing `dataroot` template in the first XSLT to this...

```
<xsl:template match="dataroot">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*)]|order"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: that's absolutely spot on, thank you so much for your help! so if I wanted to nest another element in one that I've just nested, will I essentially need to copy this part;

   <xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>


   <!-- nests all elements within order -->

       <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::order)]"/>
    </order>
   </xsl:template>

and rename "order" to the element that I want nested?

Comment: sorry, another quick question! I've managed to nest "version" in "press_section", but which part of the XSLT is the part that says to remove the un-nested element? As now I have a copy of "version" nested in "press_section" and a copy of "version" that isn't nested.

Comment: Strictly speaking, XSLT doesn't "remove" anything. It is creating a new document, so you are not "removing" elements, but simply not creating equivalent elements in the output. In this, you want to avoid creating the `version` element under the `order` element in your output. To do this, change the line `<xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::order)]"/>` in the `order` template to `<xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::order) and not(self::version)]"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much again! I assume I can just keep putting `and not(self::whateverelement)]` and creating the template matching the element to nest whatever I like?

Comment: Yes, you should! Best way is to try it, and find out ;)